# pandas: get third business day of month

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

i Have a daterange

```
pd.bdate_range("2001-01-01", "2018-01-01")
```

and want to find the third business day of the month (ignore holidays for now). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan: groupby year, month. Choose third with nth().

This example will be easier with a series:

```
dates = pd.Series(pd.bdate_range("2001-01-01", "2018-01-01"))
dates.groupby((dates.dt.year, dates.dt.month)).nth(3)
```

Partial output:

`2001  1    2001-01-04
      2    2001-02-06
      3    2001-03-06
      4    2001-04-05
      5    2001-05-04
      6    2001-06-06
      7    2001-07-05
      8    2001-08-06
      9    2001-09-06
      10   2001-10-04
      11   2001-11-06
      12   2001-12-06
2002  1    2002-01-04
      2    2002-02-06
      3    2002-03-06
      4    2002-04-04`

Answer (score 1):

As you are already in business dates, you could resample to the start of the business month ('BMS') and add an offset of 3 business days::

```
>>> pd.Series(index=pd.bdate_range("2001-01-01",
                    "2018-01-01")).resample('BMS').index + pd.datetools.BDay(3)

DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-04', '2001-02-06', '2001-03-06', '2001-04-05',
           '2001-05-04', '2001-06-06', '2001-07-05', '2001-08-06',
           '2001-09-06', '2001-10-04',
           ...
           '2017-04-06', '2017-05-04', '2017-06-06', '2017-07-06',
           '2017-08-04', '2017-09-06', '2017-10-05', '2017-11-06',
           '2017-12-06', '2018-01-04'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=205, freq=None)
```

You'll find further details on how to work with dates in pandas in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/timeseries.html).